# VBA: オブジェクト配列を変数に設定する際、「コンパイルエラー: オブジェクトが必要です。」となる。

Tags: vba

VBAでクラスを自作しました。
`test Module`の`test`メソッド実行時に、`GetSheetObjs`メソッドの戻り値をセットする行`Set GetSheetObjs = sheets`部分で、`sheets`が選択され色が反転した状態になりコンパイルエラーが発生します。

Class1

```
Option Explicit
    
    Public Sub test()
        Dim sheetName_excluded As String
        
        Dim sheetObjs As Object
        Set sheetObjs = GetSheetObjs
    End Sub
    
    'ファイルからシートオブジェクトを読み込みます。
    Private Function GetSheetObjs() As Object
        '結果シートを格納する配列変数
        Dim sheets() As Object
        
        ' Worksheets を For Next でループする
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = Worksheets(i)
    
            ReDim sheets(i)
            Set sheets(i) = ws
        Next
        
        '戻り値をセット
        Set GetSheetObjs = sheets
    End Function
```

test Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim cls1 As Class1: Set cls1 = New Class1
  Call cls1.test
End Sub
```

試したこと
・`Me.GetSheetObjs`としましたが別のエラーが出て、これではないなとおもいました。
・`Dim sheetObjs As Object`の部分を`Dim sheetObjs() As Object`としましたが、別のコンパイルエラー：配列には割り当てられません。と出ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列はオブジェクトではないです。
オブジェクトの配列でも、やはり配列です。

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim sheetName_excluded As String
    Dim sheetObjs() As Object

    sheetObjs = GetSheetObjs

    '配列の中身の確認
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(sheetObjs)
        Debug.Print sheetObjs(i).Name
    Next
    
End Sub

'ファイルからシートオブジェクトを読み込みます。
Private Function GetSheetObjs() As Object()
'結果シートを格納する配列変数
    Dim sheets() As Object

    ' Worksheets を For Next でループする
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets(i)

        ReDim Preserve sheets(i) 'Preserveがないと中身が破棄される。
        Set sheets(i) = ws

    Next

    '戻り値をセット
    GetSheetObjs = sheets
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim sheetName_excluded As String
    Dim sheetObjs() As Object
        
    sheetObjs = GetSheetObjs
    
End Sub
```

```
'ファイルからシートオブジェクトを読み込みます。
Private Function GetSheetObjs() As Object()
    '結果シートを格納する配列変数
    Dim sheets() As Object
    
    ' Worksheets を For Next でループする
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets(i)

        ReDim sheets(i - 1)
        Set sheets(i - 1) = ws
    Next
    
    '戻り値をセット
    GetSheetObjs = sheets
    
End Function
```

参考：[VBAで配列を引数・戻り値にする方法](https://qiita.com/ryosuke0825/items/93eb8a284eb5dba59f29)